# how do i adjust my code to become a recursive reverse sum loop

Tags: python, list, algorithm, recursion

I have a simple recursion method for reversing a list

lst = [1,2,3,4,5] will print as [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def revlist(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return revlist(lst[1:]) + [lst[0]]


print(revlist(lst))
```

Instead of it printing the reverse list i want it to add 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 but i dont know how to, at the end I should get 15 but not by just adding the sum of the list, only by adding at the last element and finishing at the first [0] element. Whatever I do to try and sum the array list it gives me errors and I dont really know how I can get any closer to code what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: Please show what you did to try and sum the array list and include the errors you get in your question

Comment: Also, why do you need to reverse the list to find the sum of its elements? 5+4+3+2+1 is the same as 1+2+3+4+5

Comment: When you write `5+4+3+2+1`, do you mean `(((5+4)+3)+2)+1`? Of course the results are the same, but if you want this specific order of computation, the current answer below is incorrect; that one actually computes `5+(4+(3+(2+1)))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange requirement, but it could be accomplished like this:

```
def revsum(lst):
    if not lst: 
        return 0
    return lst[-1] + revsum(lst[:-1])
```

Of course, this is purely academic, and you should never use this in real Python code.

Comment: thank you this works, yes it was a weird question im following in some academic work from a friend, will defintely not use this in the real world.

Comment: @Ethan yeah, and note, that applies to recursion more broadly when using CPython. It's inefficient and unoptimized (so tail calls aren't eliminated, for example, so you always pay for the stack space). Of course, *sometimes* recursion is a very readable and expressive way to write a particular algorith, e.g. tree traversal, but outside of those very obvious cases, stick to regular iterative code in Python, which is where it shines anyway

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum(lst[::-1])
```

It will reverse the lst using step counter(notice the two colons) then uses inbuilt sum function to add the list.